# Qt: Start process in worker-thread by calling function of worker - thread safe?

Tags: multithreading, qt, thread-safety, signals-slots, qthread

I designed an architecture, where I have permanent worker objects living in permanent separate threads and the main thread can start processes of the workers from time to time. Since the starting of the processes involves passing a large number of arguments, including custom objects I prefer not to use signals/slots to start the processes, but a function call instead, (among other things this makes the code much more readable). The signal is then emitted in the worker class itself.

This architecture **works most of the time**, but I have been experiencing **rare and completely random crashes**, which I cannot trace. I wrote a minimal example of my code and was wondering if

1. Is the mutex necessary? I included it, since, if I understand correctly, assignments and readouts of a boolean could be non-atomic.
2. Is this structure problematic? Could it be responsible for random crashes?
3. Are there obvious alternatives for implementing such a self-contained structure of worker objects which does not require addressing with signals?
4. Would it be more proper to use signals to start the process, also transmitting the complex arguments? What is best practice in this case to allow the usage of signals with custom objects as parameters?

Here is the example code for the Worker:

```
class ComplexParameter;
class Worker : public QObject{
    Q_OBJECT
signals:
    startSignal();
    finishedSignal();
private:
    bool isBusy;
    QMutex mutex;
    ComplexParameter storedCP;
    void performWork() {
        //this function runs in worker thread
    
        //time consuming process involving storedCP
    
        QMutexLocker locker(&mutex);
        isBusy = false;
        emit finishedSignal;
    }
public:
    Worker() : QObject(nullptr) {
        connect(this,&Worker::startSignal,this,&Worker::performWork,Qt::QueuedConnection);
        isBusy = false;
    }
    bool startWork(ComplexParameter cp) {
        //this function runs still in GUI Thread
        QMutexLocker locker(&mutex);
        if(isBusy) {
            return false;
        }
        isBusy = true;
        storedCP = cp; //store parameter
        emit startSignal; //this moves things to the worker thread
        return true;
    }
};
```

and an example for a function running in the main thread, using that worker

```
//some function in main thread
MainObject::someFunction() {
    QThread* thread = new QThread;
    Worker* worker = new Worker;
    worker->moveToThread(thread);
    thread->start();

    ComplexParameter cp1,cp2,cp3;
    worker->startWork(cp1); //this will make the worker start the process (in its own thread)
    worker->startWork(cp2); //the process will not start since the worker is busy

    QSignalSpy spy(worker,&Worker::finishedSignal);
    spy.wait(); //waits until worker is finished
    worker->startWork(cp3); //the process will start since the worker is no longer busy
}
```

Comment: It seems to me that the call to startWork(cp2) will return false if the thread is still running the first performWork task. That means that the worker will not run performWork with cp2 at all. Is that your intented behavior?

Comment: Yes, that it is intended. In general such calls might be initialized for example by the user in the main thread and in these cases the process will not be started if the worker is busy and the user will be informed via the false return value. (Of course in this example script that return value is not used but this is supposed to be an example just for the thread safety after all)